# Scrapy - Get index of item being parsed?

Tags: python, database, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to load some XPATH rules from a database using Scrapy.

The code I've written so far works fine, however after some debugging I've realised that Scrapy is parsing each item asynchronously, meaning I have no control over the order of which item is being parsed.

What I want to do is figure out which item from the list is currently being parsed when it hits the `parse()` function so I can reference that index to the rows in my database and acquire the correct XPATH query. The way I'm currently doing this is by using a variable called `item_index` and incrementing it after each item iteration. Now I realise this is not enough and I'm hoping there's some internal functionality that could help me achieve this.

Does anyone know the proper way of keeping track of this? I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find any info about it. I've also looked at the [Scrapy source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spider.py) but I can't seem to figure out how the list of URL's actually get stored.

Here's my code to explain my problem further:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from dirbot.items import Product

from dirbot.database import DatabaseConnection

# Create a database connection object so we can execute queries
connection = DatabaseConnection()

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    start_urls = []
    item_index = 0

    # Query for all products sold by a merchant
    rows = connection.query("SELECT * FROM products_merchant WHERE 1=1")

    def start_requests(self):
        for row in self.rows:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(row["product_url"])

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = Product()
        item['product_id'] = self.rows[self.item_index]['product_id']
        item['merchant_id'] = self.rows[self.item_index]['merchant_id']
        item['price'] = sel.xpath(self.rows[self.item_index]['xpath_rule']).extract()

        self.item_index+=1

        return item
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index (or the row id from the database) along with the request using [Request.meta](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=meta#scrapy.http.Request.meta). It's a dictionary you can access from [Response.meta](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=meta#scrapy.http.Response.meta) in your handler.

For example, when you're building your request:

`Request(url, callback=self.some_handler, meta={'row_id': row['id']})`

Using a counter like you've attempted won't work because you can't guarantee the order in which the responses are handled.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This guided me towards finding the solution :)

Comment: Sure. Also, you might just want to pass the whole row object itself, rather than the index (since you only ever use the index to access the row object in your example).

Comment: may you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353650/scrapy-how-to-import-the-settings-to-override-it

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution I came up with just in case anyone needs it.

As @toothrot suggested, you need to overload methods within the `Request` class to be able to access `meta` information.

Hope this helps someone.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request

from dirbot.items import Product

from dirbot.database import DatabaseConnection

# Create a database connection object so we can execute queries
connection = DatabaseConnection()

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    start_urls = []

    # Query for all products sold by a merchant
    rows = connection.query("SELECT * FROM products_merchant WHERE 1=1")

    def start_requests(self):
        for indx, row in enumerate(self.rows):
            self.start_urls.append( row["product_url"] )
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(row["product_url"], {'index': indx})

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url, meta):
       return Request(url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, meta=meta)

    def parse(self, response):

        item_index = response.meta['index']

        sel = Selector(response)
        item = Product()
        item['product_id'] = self.rows[item_index]['product_id']
        item['merchant_id'] = self.rows[item_index]['merchant_id']
        item['price'] = sel.xpath(self.rows[item_index]['xpath_rule']).extract()

        return item
```