# scrapy how to import the settings to override it

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

this is my code

```
class Test(Spider):
    self.settings.overrides['JOBDIR']= "seen"
```

I got:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 46, in settings
    return self.crawler.settings
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 41, in crawler
    assert hasattr(self, '_crawler'), "Spider not bounded to any crawler"
AssertionError: Spider not bounded to any crawler
```

I am extending `Spider` and I am not using `Crawler` because I don't have links nor rules to follow

I am guessing that my problem is because I didn't import the settings well and I need your help please

Comment: any answer on this ?

Comment: wasn't the answer helpful ?

Comment: @Udy i don't know i have not tried it yet. i am busy nowadays, but i will test it later, anyway +1 thanks

Answer (score 12):

In order to change the settings in the spider you can:

```
class TestSpider(Spider):

    def set_crawler(self, crawler):
        super(TestSpider, self).set_crawler(crawler)
        crawler.settings.set('JOBDIR','seen')

    # rest of spider code
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks
(Should be marked as Accepted I guess)

Comment: Just fix that missing " after `seen`

Comment: I am getting 'CrawlerSettings' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: which version to scrapy do you use ?

Comment: Since Scrapy 1.0 [`from_crawler`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.from_crawler) must be used instead of `set_crawler`.

Comment: Also since 1.0, you can and should use [`Spider.custom_settings`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider) as described in [this other answer](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/news.html#per-spider-settings-gsoc-2014).

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=custom_settings#scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings), individual settings of each spider can be set as a class attribute `custom_settings`, which should be a dictionary. In your case it will look like this:

```
class TestSpider(Spider):

    custom_settings = {'JOBDIR':"seen"}
    # The rest of the spider goes here
```

Not sure if this will work with early versions of scrapy.